# How to do explicit overloaded conversion in F# like in C#?

Tags: f#, type-conversion, c#-to-f#

Let's say that I have a class  in C# with overloaded implicit and explicit operators:

```
public static implicit operator CSClass(int a) => ...;
public static explicit operator int(CSClass a) => ...;
```

I compile this project as class library.

In F# now I can add my operator for implicit conversions and use it:

```
#r @"C:\path\to.dll"
open Some.Namespace.ToMyClass
let inline (!>) (x:^a) : ^b = ((^a or ^b) : (static member op_Implicit : ^a -> ^b) x)
let a : CSClass = !> 5
```

But how can I do an explicit overloaded conversion in F#? (`CSClass` to `int`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is my understanding that F# does not usually do explicit conversions. Instead, you would just use a function. For example, if you have a `char` and want to convert that explicitly into an `int`, in C# you write:

```
char theChar = 'A';
int convertedChar = (int)theChar;
```

In F#, the `int` operator (function) is used for the same purpose:

```
let theChar = 'A'
let convertedChar = int theChar;
```

Therefore the idiomatic way to do the conversion would be something like this:

```
module Some.Namespace.MyClass
let toInt (x : MyClass) = [...]
```

You would use it like so:

```
let convertedMyClass = MyClass.toInt myClass
```

It can also be piped:

```
funcReturningMyClass x y
|> MyClass.toInt
|> printfn "%d"
```